# Using Angular 9, How to print jspdf from html element while updating values in the html using interpolation

Tags: html, angular, jspdf

Html template

```
  <div id="download">
    <div>
      {{name}}
    </div>
  </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="captureScreen()">Download</button>
```

Component.ts:

```
  public name = 'Sample';

  captureScreen() {
    this.name = "something else";
    var img;
    var newImage;
    let filename = 'mypdf_'+'.pdf';
    var node = document.getElementById('download');
      domtoimage.toPng(node, { bgcolor: '#fff' }).then(function (dataUrl) {

        img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        newImage = img.src;

        img.onload = function () {
          var pdfWidth = img.width;
          var pdfHeight = img.height;
          var doc;
          doc = new jspdf('l', 'px', [pdfWidth, pdfHeight]);

          var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
          var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

          doc.addImage(newImage, 'PNG', 10, 10, width, height);
          doc.save(filename);

        };

      }).catch(function (error) { });
    }
```

This code works fine for a pre-set value in the name field.
I want to loop through a list of names and print a new page for every name in the pdf. But currently, if I change the value 
**this.name = "something else";**
it still outputs the name as '**Sample**' in the pdf.

How do I change the value of name on the go and print pdf for different names?

Comment: Why do you modify element while `captureScreen`?

Answer (score 0):

1) Issue is that you are trying to use `document.getElementById('download')` to query a new element which has been rendered yet, it's still rendering the old element. You need to make sure render new element first.
2) Recommend to query element by using `ViewChild` in angular.

Here is my suggestion

```
<!-- Use element reference #download to query native element -->
<div #download>
  <div>
    {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" (keyup)="changeElementText($event.target.value)">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
(click)="captureScreen()">Download</button>
```

In ts file

```
 name = 'Sample';

@ViewChild('download', {read: ElementRef})
download: ElementRef;

// Add a modify element logic, make sure modify element and render it before capture screen.
changeElementText(value: string) {
  this.name = value;
}

captureScreen() {
  let img;
  let newImage;
  const filename = 'mypdf_'+'.pdf';
  // This should provide you latest element.
  const node = this.download.nativeElement;
  console.log(node);
  /*** Your capture logic  ***/
}
```

[stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbbeed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I fixed the way I read the html element and it works. But it does not solve the main issue which is that I need to loop through the list of names I have in my ts file, and for every name I want to print the pdf. So this way works only for one name and that can be done via ngOnInit also. So maybe some how I need to render the html manually in my function captureScreen() so I can get the latest rendered html with the new name. Or any other way is also fine.